# Process an undefined number of class states

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

Let's say I have an entity `Foo`. That entity could have a 5 states: `A, B, C, D, E`(in real application number of statuses can be larger). I store that entity in a database and map it to class. Every day I run cron command that takes all records from DB:

```
records = service.getRecords()

foreach(records as record) {

}
```

So inside the `foreach` loop, I should make some actions that depend on the record status. I could use a `switch`:

```
switch(record.status) {
    case 'A': sendEmail();
    case 'B': sendSMS();
}
```

And it's good for 2-3 statuses. But I don't know how much statuses I'll have in the future. So I need a solution that allows me to add new handlers for new statuses.

I'm thinking about the chain of responsibility or state pattern. What would the best in that case?

Comment: What kinds of messages does your state machine (SM) react to?  For example, when you run your daily routine, your are [implicitly] giving your SM the "daily tick signal".  Are there other signals that you pass to your database during your daily routine?  Or, are other disjointed parts of the system responsible for other messages (while your daily routine only sends e-mails and SMS based on the state)?

Comment: No, other parts of the system don't responsible for messages. Only that routine changes the status of messages in a database to move it into another status(and does some actions for current status)

Comment: Is the state machine (workflow) strictly sequential (send e-mail after 2 days and move to state L, send SMS after 7 days and move to state M)?  Or does the workflow branch (if customer payed his bill e-mail, then go to done state Z)?

Comment: I don't have an example handy, but... https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/switch-statement-a-code-smell/ is how I'd approach it.  Basically the Jist of this and all other answers is going to be to create a mapping/context/dictionary concept to abstract out the switch into a list.

Comment: @NickAlexeev the first one. workflow strictly sequential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## In short

There is not always a perfect pattern.  Chain of responsibility and command patterns could both fit.  State pattern could make sense only in some very special cases.  The best option is a simple map of functors.

## All the details

### Option 0: Chain of responsibility pattern ?

The [chain of responsibility](https://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) allows to chain successive handlers.  Each handler would be invoked sequentially, and if a one of them matches the triggering condition (status), then its action would be executed.

Advantage:   independent handlers, that each check the status and perform the relevant action. A new status requires the implementation of a new handler and the insertion the handler in the chain.

Inconvenience:

- Error prone, because each handler is responsible of checking its own condition.  A typo in one handler could short circuit all the remaining ones.
- If you have hundreds of statuses, you'd go through them sequentially whereas most compilers are able to optimise a switch with at jump table.
- No paralelisation possible

### Option 1: Command pattern ? Perhaps

The [command pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html) allows to define a concrete command class for each status.  However, it requires to implement a [factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) that instantiates a specific command for a specific record depending on its status.

Your loop will then create a command by invoking the factory on the record that was read, and immediately invoke the command.

Advantage:  independent commands that each performs a specific action.  New statuses requires a new concrete command class and the adaptation the factory.

Inconvenience:  factory increases a little bit the complexity. And very probably will be implemented with a switch, exactly like the one you intended to avoid.

### Option 2: State pattern ? No, don't

If you have already a domain layer that can somehow retrieve domain objects from a data access layer (e.g. via a [repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)), then you may consider the [state pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state):

- Refactor your domain object, to implement the state pattern.  This implies having an abstract state class;
- Implement the different concrete state classes for the state-dependent behavior.
- Adapt the repositories and factories in order to take into account the new design
- Your cron job will then just read the domain object and perform the relevant action that will be state dependent.

ATTENTION: This makes sense if only if your domain objects have in general a state dependent behavior, i.e. not only for your cron job.  Don't use this approach if you don't have reusable domain and data access layers, or if your state dependent behavior is only for your cron job:  this would be overkill !

Inconvenience:

- Complex to implement if the foundation not already there
- Might break separation of concerns,
- Might go agains interface segregation.

### Option 3: No pattern, but a map of functors !

In the command pattern, each command has a state to memorize the parameters of the command (record + other parameters).  According to your example, you don't really need this.  So instead of a stateful command, you could just use a simple stateless functor. And then you don't need a factory.

The functor would take a record as argument and execute an action.  At the beginning of your cron job, you would construct a map, adding for each status (key of the map) the corresponding functor (value of the map).  Depending on your language, this functor could for example be:

- a function that can directly be invoked (e.g. in C)
- a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (java) or a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (C++)
- a lambda function
- a class with a static function

Your loop would then be as simple as: read the record, get the functor mapped to the status, and execute it with the record as argument.

Advantage:

- Very light solutions:  New statuses would just require to write the corresponding functor, and register it in the map.
- Easier to maintain than a switch because each action is encapsulated in a different short functor that is easy to read and understand (especially if you have hundreds of them).
- The map that finds the right functor is very efficient, especially if you have a large number of statuses.

Inconvenience:  ?

Comment: I’ve always like the map of functors myself, but there is a trade off between it and the case statement. The case is easy to break by forgetting to insert a `break` statement when adding a new case, but most compilers will warn you if you’ve not handled every case. The map of functors isn’t susceptible to accidentally causing a bug by forgetting a `break`, but you lose compiler warnings about unhandled cases. They become runtime `key not found` exceptions instead.

Comment: @RubberDuck yes, that's completely exact ! A good suite of test cases is certainly to be recommended :-)

Comment: Option 1! The factory cleanly decouples the requestor (the `foreach`) which *must* be done. Now the request has no more to do than pass `record.status`. The factory can implement any patterns (if needed), et.al. A key point of a factory is that no matter how ugly it gets at least is all in one place (and decoupled).

Comment: Consider: "Refactor" should send a shiver down your spine if existing code is well into development. Even if you should change to a state machine let's say, refactoring because of the status-processing-building implementation is the very definition of undesirable coupling. I assume the API is simple and stable (i.e. passing `record.status` & receiving an object) so decoupling - as via a factory - decouples refactoring risk.

Comment: @radarbobI Why not writing your own answer in which you could develop these arguments in more details ?

Answer (score 0):

> And it's good for 2-3 statuses. But I don't know how much statuses I'll have in the future. So I need a solution that allows me to add new handlers for new statuses.

Simply add more switch cases.

If you want to add more status values then you will have to modify your code for each new value anyway. This is unavoidable since, by your example, each status value has its own behavior. The easiest way to do that is to add switch cases.

The patterns that you mentioned in your question as possible solutions would work but they would not gain you anything. They bring additional complexity.